# How to display ancestors with XML::Twig?

Tags: perl, perl-module, xml-twig, ancestor

I do not know how to display the ancestors_or_self of one Element.

Here is the error message I get when using the method ancestors_or_self():
*Can't call method "print" without a package or object reference at xxxx*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new;
my $v= XML::Twig::Elt->new;

$v= $t->first_elt('[@id]');
$v->print;
print ("\n\n");
$v->ancestors_or_self->print;
```

thanks for your help on Perl XML::Twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ancestors_or_self` returns a list -- assuming you want the path to the element, you also want `->path` not `->print`. And as `->path` **returns** the path you will have to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new;
my $v= XML::Twig::Elt->new;

$v= $t->first_elt('[@id]');
print $v->path . "\n";
print ("\n\n");
print $_->path . "\n" foreach $v->ancestors_or_self;
```

Comment: Sorry was out of my computer for 1 day. I am trying all your solutions. Will get back to you in the next hours

Comment: your method with `path` is working. I will post the complete comments in 1 hour

Comment: your solution is the one which worked: `print $v->path . "/";
$v->print;`    THANKS !!

Comment: Actually the parent/ancestor has *an id*: `<papa id="Larry Page"> </papa>`     . I must get the following output `<papa id="Larry Page"><son> toto </son> </papa>`. Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `ancestors_or_self` returns a list, and you cannot call a method of list. Use this instead:

```
$_->print for $v->ancestors_or_self;
```

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately that command returns me the **complete XML file**, instead of just the whole path of my element $v

Comment: Well, I've answered your direct question, just fixing the syntax. If you really want to display the path of your element, perhaps `$v->path()` should be more suitable?

Comment: `$v->path()` does not display anything.  ?

Comment: how about `say $_->tag for $v->ancestors_or_self;`

Comment: `print $v->path . "/";
$v->print;` was the solution                 It seems Dre and @raina77ow found it. Many thanks !!!